# First order logic - proof outside of the deduction system

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have now started studying first order logic and I find the Fitch Style Proofs very intuitive and mechanic.
But then I encountered these two questions and although I know they're true, I have no idea how to go about proving them.

Consider $\Sigma$ a set of formulas of a first order language, and we know that $x$ does not occur in any of the formulas of $\Sigma$.

We have then to prove that if $\Sigma \cup \{ \phi \} \vdash \psi$ and $x$ does not occur free in $\psi$, then  $\Sigma \cup \{\exists x \phi \} ⊢ \psi$.

We also have to prove that if $\Sigma \cup \{ \phi \} \vdash \psi$ then $\Sigma \cup \{ \exists x \phi \} \vdash \exists x \psi$.

I would like to know how this kind of proof works, and if anyone has any idea where to find similar exercises I would be grateful.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can. Assume that you have a (Fitch) derivation $Σ \cup \{ \phi \} ⊢ \psi$ and you have to use the rules of the system to manifacture a new derivation: $Σ \cup \{ \exists x \phi \} ⊢ \psi$

Comment: Hi
I understand that if x occurs in ϕ, and we know that Σ ∪ {ϕ} ⊢ ψ, then for all x that makes Σ ∪ {ϕ}  true, it also makes ψ true. So we can infere that there exists an x such that Σ ∪ {∃xϕ} ⊢ ψ. At least I was interpreting it this way (not sure if I am right).
I am just not sure how to write a proof for this.

Comment: The "exercise" is about $\vdash$; thus IMO you have to use the inference rules and not semantics.

Comment: I think you are right, but I am still unsure how to proceed with the proof.
Would the following suffice?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CYAxMd4KGcHhw1Z_kiEaa_HlkO7E8xik/view